# Найти количество десятизначных чисел кратных 11 но при этом цифры в числах не ложны повторяться

Tags: python

Найти количество десятизначных чисел кратных 11 но при этом цифры в числах не ложны повторяться. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: Вы не можете аглгоритм составить или код? Что уже удалось сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Количество десятизначных чисел, все цифры которых различны

```
  N=9*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1=9*9!
```

Признак делимости на 11: число делится на 11, если знакочередующаяся сумма его цифр делится на 11.

```
  a1-a2+a3-a4+a5-a6+a7-a8+a9-a10=11k
```

так как все цифры различны, то максимальная сумма

```
  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0=45
```

значит кратные суммы будут 0,11,22,33,44

У нас 5 чисел стоят на четных местах, а 5 на нечетных. Причем на месте 1 не может быть 0.

Сумма для нечетных мест a1+a3+a5+a7+a9=m, тогда сумма для четных 45-m

```
  |m-(45-m)|=|45-2m|=11k, откуда m=17 и 6.
```

Сумма 5 различных цифр равна 6: 0+1+2+3 уже 6, а надо добавить еще одну цифру. Значит этот вариант не возможен.

Сумма 5 различных цифр равна 17:

```
  01259
  01268
  01349
  01358
  12347
  12356
```

Для группы включающей 0 получаем 4*4! чисел, всего 4*4!*5=4*5!

Для группы не включающей 0 получаем 5! чисел

Всего 4*5!+5!=5*5!

Количество пятизначных чисел на оставшихся четных местах 5!

Ответ: 5*(5!)^2